# Maxwell stress tensor for two interacting electric double layers

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, dielectric

Imagine two charged and parallel walls in an electrolyte solution:

[image],

with Equipotential lines as $\psi$ and electric field of $E$.

according to the Maxwell stress tensor, the stress at any point can be obtained by:

$\sigma_{ij}=-P_0\delta_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}E^2\delta_{ij}+ E\bigotimes E$.

For this system knowing that $E_x=0$, we can arrive at:

$\sigma= \begin{bmatrix}
-p_0 - \frac{1}{2}E_y^2 & 0 \\
 0& -p_0 + \frac{1}{2}E_y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

In the context of electric double layer force between two (infinite) walls, only $-p_0 + \frac{1}{2}E_y^2$ is considered. What happens to the other term? What's it significance?

Furthermore, if we use Poisson's equation, $ \nabla^2 \psi=\rho$ and Boltzmann distribution $\rho= \rho_0 e^{(-z\psi)}$, we find out that the $\sigma_{22}$ is constant between the walls, but this is not the case for $\sigma_{11}$. Doesn't this contradict with equilibrium state?